# How to bridge a VM to public IP

Tags: networking, routing, kvm, xen, bridge

I wish to to assign the IP from my eth1:2 to a VM; I also have no use of this IP for the host, it would be desirable to be exclusive to the VM.

I've ended up with a setup just like this (eth1:1, eth1:2, etc):
[Xen, bridge and multiple IPs on CentOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51826/xen-bridge-and-multiple-ips-on-centos)

And I want to route each IP to a bridge:
https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Network_Model#Routed_Configuration

I removed my eth1:2 and copied the settings to vmbr1, but it when I attempt to install a guest using that bridge the network is unreachable from the guest.

What should be changed here:

```
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
address ***from eth1:2***
netmask ***from eth1:2***
bridge_ports eth1
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
```

If someone could also point me to resources explaining scenarios and why, that would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Please copy the output of `brctl show` while the VM is running and copy the `vif` section of the Xen config file for the VM. The output of `ip addr` could potentially be useful too. The VM's virtual network interface might not be getting introduced into the bridge.

Comment: I have yet to install a VM.  Particularly with Ubuntu the automated network either fails or there is no network connection available.  If you have an image you'd suggest using to debug issues, let me know.

Comment: I reached out to customer support from my hosting provider; they have explained I must use a portable IP block for this and my statically routed IP's will not work for my needs.  I will update later with results.

Comment: If your `eth1:2` already has the address the VM is to have then you can only forward traffic using IP forward. You may want to give the bridge a connection to the VM endpoint, assign a MAC address and then let the VM (from within itself) request the IP address.